# Fail2ban named-refused failregex syntax

Tags: linux, iptables, named, fail2ban

When running the fail2ban-regex

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/named/security1.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/named-refused.conf
```

I get following output

```
Running tests
=============

Use regex file : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/named-refused.conf
Use log file   : /var/log/named/security1.log

Matched time template Day-MONTH-Year Hour:Minute:Second[.Millisecond]
Matched time template Day-MONTH-Year Hour:Minute:Second[.Millisecond]
Matched time template Day-MONTH-Year Hour:Minute:Second[.Millisecond]
Matched time template Day-MONTH-Year Hour:Minute:Second[.Millisecond]
Matched time template Day-MONTH-Year Hour:Minute:Second[.Millisecond]


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Summary
=======

Sorry, no match
```

Here is some output of the security1.log file

```
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.324 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.325 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.325 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.325 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.325 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.325 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.325 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.325 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.325 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.325 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.326 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.326 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.326 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
08-Feb-2016 11:38:15.326 client 192.168.0.1#4444 (cpsc.gov): query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied
```

the failregex is the following

```
failregex = %(__line_prefix)sclient <HOST>#\S+: (view (internal|external): )?query(?: \(cache\))? '.*' denied\s*$
```

I think there is a difference between the output of my security1.log and the failregex syntax of the named-refused.conf file which makes it not find anything.

Thanks in advance,

Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your log through my Debian 8.2 fail2ban in the same way you described and got.

```
Results
=======

Failregex: 14 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [14] ^(?:\s\S+ (?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+\(?named(?:\(\S+\))?\)?:?|\(?named(?:\(\S+\))?\)?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)\s+)?(\.\d+)?( error:)?\s*client <HOST>#\S+( \([\S.]+\))?: (view (internal|external): )?query(?: \(cache\))? '.*' denied\s*$
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [14] Day-MONTH-Year Hour:Minute:Second[.Millisecond]
`-

Lines: 14 lines, 0 ignored, 14 matched, 0 missed
```

So if your interested, the /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/named-refused.conf file in my distro is:

```
[Definition]                                                                                                                                                                    

# Daemon name                                                                                                                                                                   
_daemon=named                                                                                                                                                                   

# Shortcuts for easier comprehension of the failregex                                                                                                                           

__pid_re=(?:\[\d+\])                                                                                                                                                            
__daemon_re=\(?%(_daemon)s(?:\(\S+\))?\)?:?                                                                                                                                     
__daemon_combs_re=(?:%(__pid_re)s?:\s+%(__daemon_re)s|%(__daemon_re)s%(__pid_re)s?:)                                                                                            

#       hostname       daemon_id         spaces                                                                                                                                 
# this can be optional (for instance if we match named native log files)                                                                                                        
__line_prefix=(?:\s\S+ %(__daemon_combs_re)s\s+)?                                                                                                                               

failregex = ^%(__line_prefix)s(\.\d+)?( error:)?\s*client <HOST>#\S+( \([\S.]+\))?: (view (internal|external): )?query(?: \(cache\))? '.*' denied\s*$                           
            ^%(__line_prefix)s(\.\d+)?( error:)?\s*client <HOST>#\S+( \([\S.]+\))?: zone transfer '\S+/AXFR/\w+' denied\s*$                                                     
            ^%(__line_prefix)s(\.\d+)?( error:)?\s*client <HOST>#\S+( \([\S.]+\))?: bad zone transfer request: '\S+/IN': non-authoritative zone \(NOTAUTH\)\s*$                 

# DEV Notes:                                                                                                                                                                    
# Trying to generalize the                                                                                                                                                      
#          structure which is general to capture general patterns in log                                                                                                        
#          lines to cover different configurations/distributions                                                                                                                
#..........                                                                                                                                                                     
# (\.\d+)? is a really ugly catch of the microseconds not captured in the date detector                                                                                         
  #                                                                                                                                                                               
# Author: Yaroslav Halchenko
```

Note the authors comment about the "really ugly catch of the microseconds not captured in the date detector"
You could try it (after a sanity check against your own version of course) and see if it works. By the way, what is your distro ?

Comment: Hi Mbo42, this worked fine! It works with the microseconds aswell. Distro info:Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle)
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="17 (Beefy Miracle)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=17
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 17 (Beefy Miracle)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:17"
Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle)
Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle)

Comment: What I did is, added your last line to my rule, becuase I didn't have it, and viola...